# Extracting from Pandas Column with regex pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with the following structure:

```
pd.DataFrame([None, '1 RB, 2 TE, 2 WR', '1 RB, 1 TE, 3 WR', '1 RB, 3 TE, 1 WR', '1 RB, 0 TE, 4 WR', '2 RB, 1 TE, 2 WR', '2 RB, 2 TE, 1 WR', '1 RB, 2 TE, 1 WR,1 P,2 LB,1 LS,3 DB', '6 OL, 2 RB, 2 TE, 0 WR'])
```

| RB |
| --- |
| None |
| 1 RB, 2 TE, 2 WR |
| 1 RB, 1 TE, 3 WR |
| 1 RB, 1 TE, 3 WR |
| 1 RB, 0 TE, 4 WR |

Ideally, I would prefer to split the column into the following format:

| RB | TE | WR | P | LB | LS | DB | OL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Where each of the original column values is parsed based on the label ("1 RB" would be the value 1 in the column "RB"). The pattern will always be [# position].

How would I accomplish this? Each column value in the original dataframe column is one long string, so it isn't already an array or something. Additionally, not every value in the original dataframe column follows the same order; i.e. there isn't a common pattern in the order of RB, TE, WR-- if there isn't a value, the string does not include "0 WR" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def make_dict(g: pd.DataFrame):
    res = dict(g.values[:,[-1,0]])
    return res

grouped = df[0].str.extractall(r'(\d+)\s(\w+)').groupby(level=0)
tmp = grouped.apply(make_dict)
result = pd.DataFrame([*tmp], index=tmp.index).reindex(df.index)
print(result)

>>>

    RB  TE  WR  P   LB  LS  DB  OL
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   1   2   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1   1   3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   1   3   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   1   0   4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   2   1   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   2   2   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   1   2   1   1   2   1   3   NaN
8   2   2   0   NaN NaN NaN NaN 6
```

Comment: could you explain a little more about how this should work?

Comment: You're incredible! That worked beautifully.

Comment: @ti7 My idea is to use regular expressions to split the keys and values, because with the extractall method, it splits each line into a level. So later I grouped level0, created a dictionary for each group, and finally unpacked the dict DataFrame into a dictionary list, and created a DataFrame from this dictionary list. I don't know how to express it, you can disassemble the code to do some analysis

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step process to do it assuming that the pattern is `# position, # position ...`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([None, '1 RB, 2 TE, 2 WR', '1 RB, 1 TE, 3 WR', '1 RB, 3 TE, 1 WR', '1 RB, 0 TE, 4 WR', '2 RB, 1 TE, 2 WR', '2 RB, 2 TE, 1 WR', '1 RB, 2 TE, 1 WR,1 P,2 LB,1 LS,3 DB', '6 OL, 2 RB, 2 TE, 0 WR'])

# create a list of dictionaries
rows = []
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    data = r[0]
    try:
        # assuming the items are comma separated
        items = data.split(',')
    except:
        # ignore data like None
        continue

    row = {}
    for item in items:
        # pattern: # position
        value, key = item.strip().split()
        row[key] = value
        rows.append(row)
 

# convert list of dictionaries to dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(new_df)
```